# redirecting php file regardless of what is typed after url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am somewhat new to php, JavaScript and all those languages involved in creating a website. I was wondering how to redirect no mater what you type after a given URL i.e. when I type something else after the following url [Using custom rewrite rules in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617744/using-custom-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress/whatever_I_type_here), it always redirects me to the same site. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .htccess file and it will redirect all pages on you domain to http://newdomain.com/page.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Or if you want to redirect all pages in a folder on your domain simply type:

```
Redirect 301 /yourfolder    http://www.newdomain.com/page.html
```

Thanks Admin Alex :)

Comment: thanks a lot for you quick reply. However, I am still not quit clear on this. Where exactly would I have to type this  301 /yourfolder    http://www.newdomain.com/page.html ? In a .htaccess folder ? If so, where do I place the .htaccess folder? Thanks in advance?

Comment: In public_html where the root of your website is there should already be a file called.htaccess. Then simply add the code above into it :)